# How to print a description string near a node?

Tags: binary-tree, graphviz, dot

I have recently started to use the DOT language to describe the structure of a binary tree. The following example allows to draw a binary tree having numbers as labels inside each node.

```
graph tree {
    0 [shape=ellipse]
    1 [shape=ellipse]
    2 [shape=ellipse]
    3 [shape=ellipse]
    4 [shape=ellipse]
    0 -- 1
    0 -- 2
    2 -- 3
    2 -- 4
}
```

Now, I would like to print some additional information near each node, but not inside the ellipse containing the label of the node. In other words, how can I print a description string near a node? How should I modify the above code in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this script, with the added lines,

```
graph tree {
    0 [shape=ellipse]
    1 [shape=ellipse]
    2 [shape=ellipse]
    3 [shape=ellipse]
    4 [shape=ellipse]
    0 -- 1
    0 -- 2
    2 -- 3
    2 -- 4

node [shape=none]
edge [style="invis"]
rank="same"
subgraph { 0 -- "desc of 0" }
subgraph { 1 -- "desc of 1" }
subgraph { 2 -- "desc of 2" }
subgraph { 3 -- "desc of 3" }
subgraph { 4 -- "desc of 4" }
}
```

generates a plausible image for your description

[image]